Learndash Plugin - Corrupted pdf certificate (edge)
I am using the latest version (4.12.1) of Learndash plugin and WordPress version 6.5.2.
The issue I am facing is when (a number of users) try to print/export their certificate in Microsoft Edge they get an error message "We can't open this file something went wrong". I tested it all firefox, brave and google chrome and it works fine for every single one of those in different machines too. But, in "machines" the Edge returns this problem.
Some details, Only Learndash runs as a plugin.
My work around idea was to tweak the code and make the file to auto-download instead of opening in a new tab, but the result was a corrupted file that wont open anywhere.
The big question is: Is this a bug with Learndash ? If yes is there any tweaks to fix it for now ?
or is this a problem with Microsoft Edge ?

Did you get anywhere with this? I have this same issue and from my testing it is a bug with Edge's PDF viewing capabilities. Although I use LeanDash, I have the issue in an unrelated system too.  Downloading the PDF seems to be the only workaround I am currently aware of.

In my case the problem was a language plugin that it was attaching /language/ sometimes in the final endpoint. Check my answer below.

Very useful to know - thanks. Did some more research and seems to be a general widespread issue with Edge. Strange how it is just some PDFs in my case, these are just ones the client created from Docs and no obvious pattern. Someone said they had tested a beta version of Edge and it fixed the issue, so hopefully it will be permanently resolved soon.

The "problem" eventually was: - opening/downloading the pdf file under a language endpoint of a plugin that was installed in WordPress.
I added a script plugin to fix the problem:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var certificateLinky = document.querySelectorAll(".ld-certificate-link");

    certificateLinky.forEach(element => {
        if (element.href.includes('el'))
        {
            console.log(element.href, 'contains el');

            element.href = element.href.replace('el/', '');
            console.log('new link', element.href);
        }
        if (element.href.includes('fr'))
        {
            console.log(element.href, 'contains fr');

            element.href = element.href.replace('fr/', '');
            console.log('new link', element.href);
        }
    });

    // console.log(certificateLinky);
});



